# How to get the login user name?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I try to use servlet request to retrieve the user name after basic authentication. But I found no such method to retrieve user name. There is  method to get the user role, but not the name?

Anyone know how to get the user name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of HTTP BASIC authentication, the username is available by [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).

So, in Servlet:

```
String username = request.getRemoteUser();
// ...
```

and in JSP:

```html
<p>Welcome, ${pageContext.request.remoteUser}</p>
```

Further, the user principal is available by [`HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29).

Comment: what is the difference betwen user and principal?

Comment: The principal is just an abstraction. It contains in turn among others the username, exactly the one which `getRemoteUser()` returns. If you don't ever need to have an implementation of `javax.security.Principal` at hands, just ignore it until then :)

Comment: what if we use Principle getUserName()?

Comment: The principal is just an abstraction. It contains in turn among others the username, exactly the one which `getRemoteUser()` returns. If you don't ever need to have an implementation of `javax.security.Principal` at hands, just ignore it until then :)

Answer (score 0):

on login put the useful data in session attribute and read it where ever required

```
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("key", dataInstance);
```